# Course allocation for students with three priorities

Tags: algorithm

Im looking for an algorithm that allocates **n students** into **m courses**, where each student defines three priorities and each course has a **min** and **max** count and also an **optimal count** that lies between min and max.

What i have so far is:

- An array of courses
- An array of students with a property for their three priorities

**1)** Shuffle courses; shuffle students

**2)** loop over students and temporarily assign them into their first choice.
if their first choice is full, say at 10 students, we need to determine which of the 11 students to drop.
Since we dont have a student priority of the courses to find the weakest student to drop, we would want to find a student that has a priority 2 with open slots

This can be redone for priorities 2 and 3, but in the end it doesnt always get the best result possible..

Comment: Seems you have two conflicting objectives (student priorities and optimal-count hitting). You need to formalize this. Furthermore you need to define the losses in use. The common ones are sum-of-absolute-differences (l1) and sum-of-squared-differences (l2). Both will behave very different.

Comment: the students priorities are definitely the important part. optimal course count is rather optional. In the end the algorithm should find a solution where the deviation to students priorities is minimized for the good of all students

Comment: This is not enough. Both penalizations achieve this, but the loss is different. Read some basics about loss-functions and their effects.

Comment: ive found a series of videos covering the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euhATa4wgzo
according to my understanding the loss function calculates the difference of the desired outcome (students priorities) and the calculated outcome (actual allocation of courses)
and the sum of squared-differences is more vulnerable to outlier, as stated in the video. where an outlier is an observed deviation of the expected value. however, im finding it hard to adapt this concept to my scenario with students/courses

Answer (score 0):

The closest similar problems are probably the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem#Similar_problems) and the [hospital/resident matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program#Matching_algorithm).

You probably are looking for an *optimal* solution, which means that, given an allocation, there no other assignments(student => course) which both the student and course would prefer.

Comment: exactly, in my situation the courses dont have preferences, only students have. ive looked into the stable marriage problem, but there we have two equally sized sets. With the courses its a bit different, since we have min, max and, optimal

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks very similar to the [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem), an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) optimization problem.

Comment: i added more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you create variables Xij where Xij = 1 if student i is assigned to course j then you can write down the constraints as linear equalities and inequalities: 0 <= Xij <= 1, SUM_j Xij = 1 for all i - each student is assigned to exactly one course, min <= SUM_i Xij <= max - each course has a minimum and maximum number of students. The sum of student happiness is SUM_ij Xij Pij where Pij might be 3, 2, 1, or 0 depending on whether course j was student i's 1, 2, 3, or other choice.

You then use linear programming to maximise student happiness. If you follow through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Using_total_unimodularity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices I think you can assume that the resulting solution will have integer values for the Xij, which must therefore be 0 or 1.

To attempt to find solutions where each course is near its optimal size, I suggest that you also try to find solutions where you reduce max and increase min for each course to make them closer to the optimal size. You could, for instance, binary chop on an allowance s to find the minimum s for which there is a solution and the min and max chosen for each course are all no more that s students from the optimal size for that course.